# Concatenating structure elements

Tags: matlab, matlab-struct

For example

```
test = struct('one', [1;2;3], 'two', [4;5;6]);
```

I would like to vertically concatenate the vectors in the struct `test`. For example, if it were defined as a cell array instead `test = {[1;2;3], [4;5;6]}`, I could do `vertcat(test{:})`. However, `vertcat(test{:})` returns a `struct` object if `test` is a struct.

I would like to have a solution that does not involve creating a temporary cell array using `struct2cell`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is to actually use `struct2array` and then flatten the result.

```
A = reshape(struct2array(test), [], 1);

%   1
%   2
%   3
%   4
%   5
%   6
```

## Benchmark

As a follow-up, I have performed a little bit of a benchmark comparing the usage of `struct2cell` to `struct2array`. We would expect the `cell2mat(struct2cell())` method to be slower because 1) it is operating on cell arrays and 2) it uses cell arrays rather than numerical arrays which are notoriously slow. Here is the script I used to perform the tests.

```
function tests()
    sizes = round(linspace(100, 100000));

    times1 = zeros(size(sizes));
    times2 = zeros(size(sizes));

    for k = 1:numel(sizes)
        sz = sizes(k);
        S = struct('one', rand(sz, 1), 'two', rand(sz, 1));
        times1(k) = timeit(@()cellbased(S));
        times2(k) = timeit(@()arraybased(S));
    end

    figure;
    plot(sizes, cat(1, times1 * 1000, times2 * 1000));
    legend('struct2cell', 'struct2array')
    xlabel('Number of elements in S.a and S.b')
    ylabel('Execution time (ms)')
end

function C = cellbased(S)
    C = cell2mat(struct2cell(S));
end

function C = arraybased(S)
    C = reshape(struct2array(S), [], 1);
end
```

And the results (R2015b)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I managed to do it using:

```
cell2mat(struct2cell(test))
```

Comment: Why do you have a self-answer where you use `struct2cell` despite explicitly stating in your question that you *don't* want to use `struct2cell`? Also you do realize that this still creates a temporary cell array, right?

Comment: Sorry, to be precise I did not want to assign a temporary variable explicitly with `tmp = struct2cell`. I did not realise it creates a temporary cell array. It was just the solution I found so it was worth posting in case no one had a better answer.

Comment: You can think of it kind of like `mean(rand(1e10,1))`. This is still going to consume all of the memory required to hold the random array even though the end result is a single number. I have added a benchmark to my answer to show the performance difference between these two solutions.